# Functionally order data frame columns by date

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame,

```
ESIVmatrix <- structure(c(1000, 1050, 1100, 1150, 1200, 1250, 0.596044633067339, 
0.568874415146119, 0.548817842630467, 0.528509198265979, 0.505102479305053, 
0.481863859161313, 0.419829588814411, 0.407383853187116, 0.395662104352744, 
0.383710399971056, 0.371402827197033, 0.358943850461579, 0.390669388091009, 
0.380556007177402, 0.369862565005378, 0.358004628064117, 0.347655431619544, 
0.33661166544938, 0.474661141683071, 0.457000912081753, 0.444006689151462, 
0.429723103151982, 0.415839741238857, 0.400624512403368), .Dim = c(6L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Strikes", "20150417", "20150918", 
"20151218", "20150619")))
```

The order of the columns however, is not in date sequential order. I would like them to be in date sequential order (20150417, 20150619, 20150918,20151218).

I have tried using `order()` and `arrange()` to no avail. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try ordering on just the columns (i.e. the second argument of `[`):

```
ESIVmatrix[, order(colnames(ESIVmatrix))]
```

This works, but leaves the `strikes` column last.  You can workaround with a slightly more complex order:

```
ESIVmatrix[, c(1, order(colnames(ESIVmatrix)[-1]) + 1)]
```

Produces:

```
     Strikes  20150417  20150619  20150918  20151218
[1,]    1000 0.5960446 0.4746611 0.4198296 0.3906694
[2,]    1050 0.5688744 0.4570009 0.4073839 0.3805560
[3,]    1100 0.5488178 0.4440067 0.3956621 0.3698626
[4,]    1150 0.5285092 0.4297231 0.3837104 0.3580046
[5,]    1200 0.5051025 0.4158397 0.3714028 0.3476554
[6,]    1250 0.4818639 0.4006245 0.3589439 0.3366117
```

We resort to some trickery here because we need the first column to stay in the first place.  Consider:

```
c(1, order(colnames(ESIVmatrix)[-1]) + 1)
```

Here we say:

- Give us the first column: `c(1, ...`
- And then order all but the first column by column names: `order(colnames(ESIVmatrix)[-1])`
- We then need to add `+ 1` to the last piece because `order` just returns the indeces relative to what is being ordered, which in this case is missing the first column, so we have to offset everything back by one

Comment: Alternative: `ESIVmatrix[,c("Strikes",sort(colnames(ESIVmatrix)[-1]))]`

Comment: @thelatemail, agreed, I had actually considered that one too but decided to go with the slightly more general if less intuitive `order` version.